# Which answer should be marked as accepted-answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

My question was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778164/how-to-check-if-a-constraint-exists-in-java/42780269#42780269)

---

I received 2 answers for the question. The first one answers the question upto the mark. The second one doesn't directly answer the question but it solves the underlying problem which makes the question invalid. I am convinced that both the answers are correct in a way solved my problem from different perspectives.

In such cases which answer should be marked as accepted?

Comment: Whichever solution helps you the most?

Comment: Accept the answer that answers the question, upvote the second one? That's how I'd go on about it. You can also award a bounty, I don't know if that's necessary though.

Comment: If I mark whichever solution which helped me the most, most beginners usually just look at accepted answers and the "actual" correct one might not be upvoted as much and people with stakes might miss it. Have a look at this one - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias

Comment: If that's your worry, don't accept either, just upvote both of them.

Comment: That is the status quo!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't agree with not accepting any of them, as it will make the community user bump the question again and again from time to time.

Comment: @Walfrat What do you suggest

Comment: I'd say accept the one which fix the problem at its root, users just searching for code will find the other one.

Comment: @Walfrat If there's any answers with a positive score then Community won't touch it.  Not that that's a reason to take any particular action in the first place.

Comment: @Servy I meant the question will be bump in the question list by community as long there is no accepted answer.

Comment: @Walfrat I did now accept whichever fixed the problem at it's root.

Comment: ok I will make an answer there to explain the things about the community bump

Comment: @Walfrat No, *it won't*.  Community will only bump questions where there is at least one answer and all of the answers have a score of 0.

Comment: @Servy my bad, i edited my answers, there are still some point that make it better than not having any accepted answers.

Comment: @Walfrat No, "having accepted answers" isn't inherently good for its own sake, and you shouldn't be pushing people to accept answers when they don't feel it's appropriate.

Comment: @Servy But, in my case or a similar one, the problem is one of them solved my problem directly. Other deemed that problem is an invalid one and out of scope, which is also a solution to the problem. I do find Mr Walfrat's answer reasonable since, by asking the question, I created an issue which probably shouldn't exist and an answer to it is just a band aid to the symptom and doesn't really address it. Your thoughts please.

Comment: @TarunMaganti Sounds like your question, and both of the answers aren't really helpful in general then.

Comment: @Servy Probably so. But, there might be cases where people could get a similar question in the context and the reason for which Mr. Walfrat mentions they find out that they are looking in the wrong perspective to a problem.

Comment: @TarunMaganti That's not actually what that answer says at all.  It also assumes that other people will have that same underling problem, rather than looking for an answer to the question asked for an entirely different reason.

Comment: @Servy So, like you stated in your answer, I should probably accept the one which I followed regardless of the relation of answers to the question and up vote (not in your answer) which I find are insightful into the problem.

Comment: @TarunMaganti Sure.

Comment: @Servy Thank you for your time.